# Perl Threads - shared hash reference

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, share

In the below code (part of bigger script) a different result is received each time for the 2  prints of $ref_h_report, although the script 'works' i.e. same hash is referenced in both subs. Why does the print give different results ? can this cause any problems ?

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %h_report;
my $ref_h_report = share(%h_report);

$thr=threads->create(\&run_test)
$thr->join();
&merge_report;

sub run_test {
.....
$ref_h_report{'test'} = 'PASSED';
print "reference=%0d\n", $ref_h_report;
.....
}

sub merge {
if($ref_h_report{'test'} eq 'PASSED')
print "reference=%0d\n", $ref_h_report;
}

}
```

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;` Is `$ref_h_report`  a string or a reference to a hash?

Comment: @M42 $ref_h_report is the reference to the hash that is returned from share(%h_report) (see code snippet above)

Comment: So you have to use: `$ref_h_report->{'test'} = 'PASSED';`. And, what do to want to print. Your script throws errors with `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: There is no `%` after the `share`...

Comment: please show your actual code, copied and pasted.  this has several errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl threads implement shared variables with magic.  Each thread will have its own copy of a shared container for a variable and changes to it will be propagated to the master copy.  But the containers are separate.

Comment: what is the suggested way to avoid the chdir problem ?(original code too long to post, Ive fixed 1 typo that was pointed out), 10x

Comment: So don't use `chdir`.

Comment: or don't use threads.  threads often introduce more problems than they solve in Perl, and there is usually a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get inspiration from [The Wide Finder Project](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/09/20/Wide-Finder). There is nice [solution](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~sorourke/wf.pl) in [Results](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/10/30/WF-Results) made by Sean O’Rourke. It can don't work for you when number of keys is much bigger than benefit from parallelization. It can also be killed by slow IO.